# analyze program performance

Tags: c#, performance

I have a program and I have encountered some performance issues.
I want to be able to track how long it takes for every single function in my code to run.

please recommend me a tool that can do as stated.

EDIT:

are there any free/open source tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), JetBrains are very good.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS 2010 you can use it's [profiling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/) tools to accomplish exactly what you want

Comment: isn;t it only available in the ultimate team edition? im poor.

Comment: Also SharpDevelop has some profiling tools, it's opensource and you can open your VS2010 solutions

Answer (score 0):

I have a positive experience with [SlimTune Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/). It's lightweight, free and pretty powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Three options. 
1) As Joe says, Jetbrains DotTrace. I use this. It's nice and simple.

2) As M0sa says, Visual Studio has profiling tools, but only in Ultimate and premium editions.

3) Redgate do Ants Profiler. Apparently it's much better these days. I rejected it years ago because it was slow and a memory hog. Probably worth looking at.

There are also some tools available for free for specific technologies. If you download the Windows 7 SDK that includes a suite of performance tools include the WPF performance tools. FYI they aren't all just for Windows 7.